# COALESCE db2 date

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to query on 2 different date fields and one date field (datefield2) has null values.  My date field is CCYYDDD and I usually convert this to mm/dd/yyyy by date(digits(datefield)) as NewDate.

This fails

`SELECT type, date(digits(datefield1)) AS DateEntered, coalesce(varchar(datefield2),'') as Renewed
FROM MYDATA
WHERE date(digits(datefeld1)) between '06/01/2015' and '6/30/2015' OR date(digits(coalesce(varchar(rendt7),''))) between '06/01/2015' and '06/30/2015'`

The following succeeds

`SELECT type, date(digits(datefield1)) AS DateEntered, coalesce(varchar(datefield2),'') as Renewed
FROM MYDATA
WHERE date(digits(datefeld1)) between '06/01/2015' and '6/30/2015' OR coalesce(varchar(rendt7),'') between '2015152' and '2015181`

How can I query where my date fields contain null values?  I plan on passing parameters in for the date range values and would rather just pass mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: 1) Don't use `BETWEEN` (at all), or any other inclusive upper-bound (`<=`) on anything not an explicit integer count, because you can get wrong data.  technically, a `DATE` datatype doesn't really have a format (that's display only), but that's not a problem if you're using the correct host variable type.  Calling `DATE(DIGITS(...))` on your column is going to make the optimizer ignore indices.  If, however, you translated the incoming host variables to the column type, it could use the index (because the format is searchable - although better to use an actual date type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your question, but I think what you're really looking for is the [TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-153) function. I *think* it would be something like this:

```
SELECT 
     type
    ,DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(datefield1,'YYYYDDD')) AS DateEntered
    ,DATE(COALESCE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(datefield2,'YYYYDDD'),'0001-01-01')) AS Renewed
FROM MYDATA
WHERE DATE(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(COALESCE(datefield1, rendt7),'YYYYDDD'))
    BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
```